# Montar uma pesquisa dinâmica

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Como fazer uma pesquisa com filtro no banco de dados usando esse exemplo a seguir:

As variáveis do banco são:

```
Nome Professor T | Matricula T |Nome Professor S | Matricula S | Nome Professor A | Matricula A | Turma | Ano | Unidade | Modalidade | Tipo do Professor .
```

**Obs**: a variável Tipo mostraria na tabela de pesquisa qual o tipo do professor " A S ou T".

Os professores podem variar de tipo dependendo das 4 ultimas variáveis do banco.

**Como assim?**

O professor pode ser T em uma determinada Unidade e em outra ele poder ser S.

Então no campo da pesquisa ao digitar o nome do professor ou matricula, a pesquisa mostraria a seguinte tabela com os dados :

```
Professor | Matricula | Unidade |  Modalidade | Ano | Turma | Tipo do Prof.
```

Alguma ideia de como monta essa pesquisa ? "Qualquer duvida e só
pergunta"

As partes em ja cheguei:

A Html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
</script>

<head>
  <title>WEB VIDEO AULAS</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->


</head>

<body>
  <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" size="35" id="palavra" placeholder="Digite seu nome ou sua matrícula.." required />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-blue" id="buscar" type="button">Buscar</button>
                        </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dados"></div>
  </div>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SLP/css/css/CDTpag2.css">
  <script>
    $('#buscar').click(function() {
      if ($("#palavra").val().length < 1) {
        Alert("digite uma palavra")
        return false;
      } else {
        buscar($("#palavra").val());
      }
    });

    function buscar(palavra) {
      var page = "/SLP/css/css/busca.php";
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: page,
        beforeSend: function() {
          $("#dados").html("Carregando...");
        },
        data: {
          palavra: palavra
        },
        success: function(msg) {
          $("#dados").html(msg);
        }
      });
    }


    $('#buscar').click(function() {
      buscar($("#palavra").val())
    });
  </script>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SLP/css/css/voltar.css">
  <a href="Pesquisa" class="bt btn-blue">Limpar</a>
  <br/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SLP/css/css/voltar.css">
  <a href="Sistema de Lotação" class="bt btn-blue">Voltar</a>
</body>

</html>
```

E a PHP :

```html
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');?>
<?php
 $host = "localhost";
   $user = "root";
   $pass = "";
   $banco = "slp";
   $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysqli_error());
   mysqli_select_db($conexao, $banco) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));

$palavra = $_POST['palavra'];

$sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * from cadastros WHERE nomeProfEfetivo LIKE '%".$palavra."%' OR matricula LIKE '%".$palavra."%'");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
?>
  <section class="panel col-lg-9">

    <header class="panel-heading">
      <br/><br/>

    </header>
    <?php
    if($row>0){
    ?>
      <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th><i class="icon_profile"></i> Professor</th>
            <th width="15"><i class="icon_profile"></i> Matricula</th>
            <th><i class="icon_mail_alt"></i> Unidade</th>
            <th width="5"><i class="icon_profile"></i> Modalidade</th>
            <th width="5"><i class="icon_mail_alt"></i> Ano</th>
            <th width="10"><i class="icon_profile"></i> Turma</th>
            <th width="10"><i class="icon_mail_alt"></i> Turno</th>
            <th width=""><i class="icon_mail_alt"></i> Tipo do Prof.</th>
          </tr>
          <?php 
            while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            ?>
          <tr>
            <td width="15">
              <?=$linha['nomeProfEfetivo'];?>
            </td>
            <td width="15">
              <?=$linha['matricula'];?>
            </td>
            <td width="15">
              <?=$linha['unidade'];?>
            </td>
            <td width="15">
              <?=$linha['modalidade'];?>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center">
              <?=$linha['ano'];?>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center">
              <?=$linha['turma'];?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?=$linha['turno'];?>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center">
              <?=$linha['tipo']; ?>
            </td>


          </tr>

          <?php }?>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <?php 
       
 }else{?>
      <h4>Nao foram encontrados registros com esta palavra.</h4>
      <?php }?>
  </section>
```

Comment: Podes explicar o que já fizeste e qual a parte em que não conseguiste avançar?

Comment: Ver la em em cima inserir os códigos de aonde já cheguei. Parte que não consigo avança e na tabala inserir varias variável em um luga só na tabela ex: o nome do professor eu só consigo bota se for um nome de um tipo só..